# Running Method on Client ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll

I would like to know how to call a method. From the Client. We have a custom Printer that runs on IIS ASP.net.

ex: method call Printer.Print(); Inside a API of the printer which is referenced over the project and Published into IIS.

```
using Printerdll;

public ActionResult Index(){

  Printerdll.Printer Freenter = new Printerdll.Printer();

  Freenter.Open();


 return View();
}
```

Now the this works even if we access the Site from the network.

But this runs only on the Server where the driver is Installed.

If the driver is installed in the Clients computer is it possible to call the method in the clients computer instead of the Server? If so, is it possible to call it without using ActiveX call that needs Internet Explorer to access?

Comment: You can call the javascript function `window.print()`.  Other than that there is no **easy** way to get .NET code to run on a client machine via a web site.

Comment: our company actually used, ActiveX to call the method using runat. But the problem is we have to use InternetExplorer for it and enable activeX. Which is tedious, you mentioned no "easy" way, can you please provide me hint about the hard way? I have no problem reading a bunch of suggestion or articles about it, only problem is, I don't know where to start.

Comment: If any website i visit is asking me to install/enable activeX , I am never using that website again !

Comment: It is an private IIS site. Not to be uploaded outside the web. Intranet.

Comment: And you're absolutely right. That is why I am asking if there is a way of avoiding the ActiveX part.

Comment: What do you mean by printer? Is it a physical printer? A job? Or does it print text to screen?

Comment: We have a Cheque Scanner Printer. It scans many batch of cheques, and it can also print on the Cheque. I just mentioned Printer because this kind of machine is not common in public.

Comment: You would have to check the API of the printer driver. You may be able to use the DLL on the client using a clientside application.  But the IIS server itself cannot execute serverside code on the client.

Comment: `window.print()` will open the browser's print dialog. That is all the control you have over printing on the client side (unless you use ActiveX/IE).

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the not-so-easy way.  Other's may have ideas about how to improve on this.  If you have a good idea for improvement go ahead and leave a comment or just edit the answer.

The broad strokes are:

- Make up a new protocol scheme, something like:  myawesomeness://
- Write an application that registered itself as a protocol handler for the newly created scheme.
- In your web page issue an ajax call to myawesomeness://url/data

  - This would invoke the aforementioned app and you can take it from there.

Some light reading about [Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).